# undefined method `symbolize_keys' for "myparamsimtryingtopass":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So im still very new to ruby on rails and what Im trying to do here is very simple. Im trying to create a facebook like app where if you click on the profile picture of a post it will direct you to the users profile page. I have just done something really similar in a online course but I cant seem to get this one to work in another view. Here is what I have that works in my header, navbar.

**NAVBAR**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  ......
  <li><%= link_to "Show Profile" , 
          user_profile_path(current_user.id, current_user.full_name) %></li>
   ....
</nav>
```

This code works and directs me to the corresponding users profile page.

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ....
  root 'statuses#index'

  get '/:id/:full_name', to: 'profile#show' , as: :user_profile
  .....
end
```

**Problem View**

```
<div class="page-header">
....
<% @statuses.each do |status| %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <%= link_to image_tag(status.user.avatar.url(:thumb),
            user_profile_path(status.user.id, status.user.full_name)) %>
        //the above is what gives me the error in the title.
      </div>
<% end %>
```

I have done my fair share of searching around and it seems that this error occurs if im passing in strings when it accepts hashkeys? Im not entirely sure. If there is a better way to do this that I should use please show me as I am very new and open to learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a wrong usage of a link_to helper. Instead of:

```
 <%= link_to image_tag(status.user.avatar.url(:thumb), user_profile_path(status.user.id, status.user.full_name)) %>
                                          ^first argument                            ^second argument
```

Use:

```
 <%= link_to user_profile_path(status.user.id, status.user.full_name) do %>
     <%= image_tag(status.user.avatar.url(:thumb)) %>
 <% end %>
```

As you can see, you pass **_path** helper as the second argument to the **image_tag**, this is wrong. The second argument to the **image_tag** should be a hash, thats why you have a `undefined method 'symbolize_keys' for` errors.